# posting large JSON string with Jersey client on android

Tags: java, android, json, rest, jersey-client

I need to post large JSON string from android to a webservice using Jersey client. The below code fails with HTTP status 505 error. Looks like the length of the JSON string is causing the trouble because the call works fine when the length of JSON string is not too high(I tested with 200 characters lenght). I also suspect this has something to do with jersey library on android because the same exact code works fine from Jersey client running in eclipse. In eclipse I don't even have to set the compression header in the request. Does anybody have a clue what is that I'm missing here ?

```
formData.add("payload",payload);
config = new DefaultClientConfig(); // SSL configuration
config.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES,
        new HTTPSProperties(JerseyClientBKS.getHostnameVerifier(), JerseyClientBKS.getSSLContext(getApplicationContext())));
ServiceFinder.setIteratorProvider(new AndroidServiceIteratorProvider()); 
client = Client.create(config);
webResource =  client.resource(getSeletctedAddress()+"/api/document/submitHybridJSON");
builder = webResource.queryParams(formData).getRequestBuilder();
for (NewCookie c : getCookies()) {
    if (c.getValue().indexOf("_") != -1){
        builder = builder.cookie(c);
    }
}
builder = builder.header("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
builder = builder.header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
Log.d(TAG, "posting.... =  ");
response =builder.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class);
Log.d(TAG,"response code "+response.getStatus());
Log.d(TAG,"valuesets "+response.getEntity(String.class));
```

Comment: 5xx errors should have details about them in the server's error log. Look there for clues.

Comment: @MarcB I use jboss , I see nothing in the server.log as if the server didn't receive the request. Do you know where else I can find the information about the error? As I said it has to be something to do with the length of the JSON string.

Comment: 200 bytes is nothing, even 200 kB should be no problem. Try to remove the headers with "gzip". I think it is not your job to set them, this should do Jersey if apropriate.

Comment: I added the header for gzip after I see the error when I was trying to send 20,000 length string . As I mentioned it is something to do with android+jersey client, because the same exact code works when I run the jersey client posting 20,000 length JSON string from eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by posting an InputStream instead of long JSON string.

Comment: How about posting example   ?